# Are rotated bounding boxes valid for training the Tensorflow object detection API?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection-api

I want to detect scratches using the object detection api and most of the time, they are not horizontal or vertical lines. Thus, I get too much background in the samples and recognition results are too poor. Does someone tried with rotated bounding boxes?

I am using this public defect dataset to test the api.  Reference: http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/conferences/dagm/2007/prizes.html One sample image is attached below.

[image]

In case I define 2 classes: Defect and no-defect class. To my way of thinking, I guess will be better if the bounding box of the defect includes as less background (no-defect area) as possible. Am I right? Any suggestion or opinion?

In my previous test, using bounding boxes with no rotation, the accuracy results are less than 50%.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge that API is good only for objects and not defects, if anyone finds how to apply this API to defect please post the answer

Comment: @Ajinkya The object recognition api can detect anything you want if you train the model properly. It can detect defects too. I tried to detect dents and results were not so bad. However, scratches looks like lines and most of the time, they has rotation. For example, if training for 2 classes: defect and non-defect, and too much non-defect area (background) is shown in defect samples, this will definitely affect the results.

Comment: I tried this one for corrosion got 15% accuracy with bounding boxes I am trying (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim/README.md) maybe can help in improving the accuracy

Comment: I got 40% using the object recognition api using dent images only. I guess I will have to work on a segmentation approach rather than object detection.

Comment: i have the same problem ! since i'm trying to detect documents and of course they can be positioned in different angles !! did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: @user3816569 no solution to that issue. 2 options: you use no rotated bounding boxes for object detection or use blobs for segmentation approach.